# I cannot figure out why my while loop is looping two times instead of just once

Tags: java

Fairly straight forward question. I am trying to get this while loop to iterate only 1 time, to display either chute or ladder. But upon execution it runs through the loop two times. EDIT: I have also have a for loop implemented beforehand and with the same results.

```
public static String writeLogFile(String filename, int[] gameBoard) {
  File fileStream = null;
  PrintWriter outputFile = null;
  String logFileName = null;
  int i = 0;
  
  try {
     logFileName = filename.replace(".", "_log.");
     
     fileStream = new File(logFileName);
     outputFile = new PrintWriter(fileStream);
     
     while(gameBoard.length > i) {
        if(gameBoard[i] > 0) {
           System.out.println("Ladder at square " + i);
        } 
        else if(gameBoard[i] < 0) {
           System.out.println("Chute at square " + i);
        }
        ++i;
     }
  } 
  catch(FileNotFoundException b) {
     logFileName = "null";
     System.out.println("ERROR! Cannot create log file.");
  }
  
  outputFile.close();
  
  return logFileName;
```

Comment: If it should run once, an if statement instead of a while is enough, isn't it?

Comment: What is the value of `gameBoard.length`? In other words, how many elements are in the array `gameBoard`?

Comment: Why do you need an array, if you are only checking the state of a variable? The point of using an Array is to iterate through all the instance of the Array. If you only check the value at index 0, then you don't need an Array and you don't need the loop, just a simple if statement to check the value at a given index.

Comment: If you need this part of the code to run exctly and only one time, then why executig a loop here ?

Comment: Don't I need a loop to iterate through an array? And gameBoard.length is dependent on file input brought in from another method.

Comment: The data is stored in an Array. Each chute or ladder is stored in the array in their respective index (based on square in the board game).

Comment: *Don't I need a loop to iterate through an array?* - you need a loop if you want to check all the values in the array. Otherwise you only need the "index" to check a specific value in the array.

Comment: If your goal is to iterate only one time then you certainly don't need a loop and you don't need arrays, like others said

Comment: The goal is to check each index of the array, and depending if the value is positive(ladder) or negative(chute) to display which square(index) each ladder/chute is on. So isn't iterating through the entire Array necessary? Ill also add that each test has different inputs for each of the data values(all from file input).

Comment: It would help if you posted sample input as well as expected and current output for that input.

Comment: input: 31
3 19
5 3
11 15
20 9
17 -13
19 -12
21 -12
27 -26

output:
run:
Enter gameboard data input filename:
gb1.txt
Gameboard setup with 30 squares
  4 squares have a chute
  4 squares have a ladder

Ladder at square 3
Ladder at square 5
Ladder at square 11
Chute at square 17
Chute at square 19
Ladder at square 20
Chute at square 21
Chute at square 27
Ladder at square 3
Ladder at square 5
Ladder at square 11
Chute at square 17
Chute at square 19
Ladder at square 20
Chute at square 21
Chute at square 27
Log file gb1_log.txt successfully created

Comment: To add to my previous comment to clarify. The first number in input is board size (minus 1) and each set of numbers dictates 1) what tile the chute(negative) or ladder(positive) is on.

Comment: It seems that you call the method `writeLogFile()` twice, because the method itself iterates one once over the complete `gameBoard` array.

Comment: Oh my god, that was it. I have instruction to determine if that method returns an exception, and used it in an if switch in the main method. Thank you so much. Now just how to figure out to determine if this method throws an exception.

Comment: Kindly, edit your Question to contain the input and output you've mentioned in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If the length of `gameBoard` is more than 1, the while-loop is going to continue to execute until it's complete. If you only want it to execute once when finding a ladder or schute then you need to `break`.

```java
     while(gameBoard.length > i) {
        if(gameBoard[i] > 0) {
           System.out.println("Ladder at square " + i);
           break;
        } else if(gameBoard[i] < 0) {
           System.out.println("Chute at square " + i);
           break;
        }
        ++i;
     }
```

Comment: I have tried this previously. This results in the program displaying the first index two times then exits the loop.

run:
Enter gameboard data input filename:
game3.txt
Gameboard setup with 100 squares
  10 squares have a chute
  9 squares have a ladder

Ladder at square 1
Ladder at square 1
Log file game3_log.txt successfully created
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you call the method `writeLogFile()` twice, because the method itself iterates one once over the complete `gameBoard` array.

> I have instruction to determine if that method returns an exception, and used it in an if switch in the main method. Thank you so much. Now just how to figure out to determine if this method throws an exception.

Then maybe you should not catch the `FileNotFoundException` within your method, but instead declare it as thrown exception:

```
public static String writeLogFile(String filename, int[] gameBoard) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // ...
}
```

Then you can catch the exception in your main method.